# Filling observable collection to display in datagrid control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-6, entity

Recently I've started a project with Entity Framework 6 and WPF application. Both of these things I am very new at, but slowly I'm getting there.

My database is up & running, a SQL Server database. I'm trying to show a table on a datagrid, using a binding item source and binding columns. I've also determined that the best way, with sights on what the application should be able to do, would be to use an observable collection.

This is what is currently in my viewmodel

```
private ObservableCollection<Table1> _columnCollection = new ObservableCollection<Table1>();
public ObservableCollection<Table1> ColumnCollection
{
get
{
return this._columnCollection;
}
set
{
_columnCollection = value;
}
}
```

My View.xaml datagrid file

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="6" x:Name="Datagrid" HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False"

ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ColumnCollection}">

<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And the data class

```
public class Table1
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The datagrid shows up empty however.
Does observablecollection not pick up all available columns that are in the SQL table this way?
And if not, how do I do that?

Comment: Where are you setting the daracontext if your view? Have you debugged this to prove you got your data in that observablecollection? Btw. Always implement inotifypropertychanged on all viewmodels. Always. Stick the implementation in a base class and inherit all vm from that. Don't present ef classes directly to the view. Use automapper ( or something similar ) to copy data to viewmodels and back to new models. This way you don't pollute models with stuff shouldn'g be in them and you have separate objects to validate.

Comment: @Andy The datacontext is set via a locator. I've tested some easier commands to make sure it's properly set, and all these commands were succesfull. Will be using notifypropertychanged from now on, thanks for that. I'll try debugging as well

Comment: IMHO, if you are "just starting" you should start with ef .net core/6. ef6 is effectively dead.

Comment: @Andy debugging shows that it does carry data. The headers as they are specified in the class do show up, the actual data that is in the table does not

Comment: @polygone321 Does the columns within SQL match up the models properties? e.g. `Id = Id` or is it something like `Id = TableOneID -- From the database`

Comment: @LV98 The first one, all columns have the same name. The only thing I can think of is that the actual SQL table is named SQLTestTable (The one that the class Table1 initiates). Could this be the cause of the issue? (And if so, how do I change it?)

Comment: @LV98 Forgot to mention this is because of the dbset class file which is public dbset <Table1> SQLTestTable { get; set;}

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your Table1 class inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged which should look something like this:

```
public class Table1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private int _ID;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set
        {
            _ID = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get{return _Name;}
        set
        {
          _Name = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

}
```

This makes the GridView update with the binded values

If I understood your question correctly, this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) The gridview does show the column names from the database now yeah, but is still showing up empty on the rows. So my guess is the collection doesnt pick these up (most likely faulty code in my viewmodel?) Any idea as to why?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but when you bind ID and Name, you are using "path =" which will bind it to that property of the itemsource. Your itemsSource is ColumnCollection, which on its own does not have that property. If you remove "Path= ID" and instead just write "{Binding ID}" it should be binding to the object of your ColumnCollection instead. I am not 100% sure about this though, but it could be worth a try.